# scopes in eager loading conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have a scope in the child model:

```
class Message
  scope :non_system, -> { where('user_id != 0') }
```

This is the initial version of my parent model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
```

The problem is that if I specify the scope in the presentation layer on the eagerly loaded child that will spawn a new query:

```
#Eager loading in the controller
groups.includes(:messages)

#in the presentation entity
#This will create a new query
group.messages.non_system
```

---

One possible solution for this is to use another association on the presentation layer:

```
group.non_system_messages.last
```

Then create that assotiation on the parent object with a custom query containing the scope:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :messages
   has_many :non_system_messages, -> { non_system }, class_name: "Message"
```

However I feel the above solution a little dirty. It repeats the information about the child entity.

Any ideas are welcome